# Accessing local MySQL server from my docker container

Tags: mysql, django, docker, django-models, docker-compose

I have a mysql server and a docker container running on my machine. In the docker container, I run a django website. I want to connect to the local mysql server from the docker container. How can I do that?

Comment: can you add your docker-compose file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score -1):

I usually do ( for testing purposes ) :

```
docker network create -d my-bridge
docker run --network my-bridge --name app-db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -e 
MYSQL_DATABASE=myapp -e MYSQL_USER=myapp_user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=myapp_secret 
mysql:latest
docker run --network my-bridge --name app -p 80:80 -e DB_HOST=app-db -e DB_USER=myapp_user -e DB_PASS=myapp_secret -e DB_NAME=myapp  myapp:latest
```

In my app Dockefile I am using in entrypoint something like envsubst, or if code language can read from environment variables I dont need to setup this.

Forget about `--link` docker parameter  -> its obsolete

Comment: when I tried the 2nd command, I got an error like `ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'`